# Replace character order MySQL field

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, datepicker, format

I have a mysql column "datepicker" where I have been storing the date in this format "m/d/Y" and now I would like to change existing data to "d-m-Y". Is there an UPDATE command to make it quickly for all the matches without having to create a query for each date?

Sample:

```
UPDATE `signup` SET `datepicker` = '18-12-2020' WHERE `datepicker` = '12/18/2020';
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't store dates as strings. MySQL has a perfectly good data type for it: `DATE`.

Comment: If your data is strings and you want to change those strings, you'd need to write the string manipulation logic to perform that change.  If your data is actual date values (column data type `DATE`) then you don't need (or want) to do this.  Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: Tip: MySQL, like most SQL databases, prefers [ISO-8601 date format, `YYYY-MM-DD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Don't use `d-m-Y`. Convert it. Use a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column to store these values. `d-m-Y` is completely useless as a format. You end up with January 10th coming after February 1st when sorted, and that's presuming it isn't *actually* October 1st and January 2nd.

Comment: So maybe change the TYPE, and make a DATE_FORMAT conversion, then adapt the format of that field on the rest of my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a good move. You're converting your data from a nonstandard format to the ISO8601 standard.  It would be even better if you changed the data type of the column to `DATE`. But do this first.

You can use [MySQL's date processing capabilities](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to do what you need.

Start with this. It should find your dates in the format you're moving away from, and display them in the dbms's canonical date format.  This is for testing, because the UPDATE is destructive and you want to make sure you have it right.

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE(datepicker, '%c/%d/%Y')) new_datepicker, datepicker
  FROM signup
 WHERE datepicker RLIKE '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$';
```

When you're sure you get what you want here, you can do this.

```
UPDATE signup
   SET datepicker = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(datepicker, '%c/%d/%Y'))
 WHERE datepicker RLIKE '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$';
```

Now you should have the right string format in your `datepicker` column.

Comment: Would never figure it out by myself, thanks! 
I've tried a str_to_date and dateformat conversion before the type change but the results were never as expected. 
Thanks again!